# Vertices to curve

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices

Is there a way to turn some simple lines made of vertices into a curves?

I have few hundred of those , it would save me the trouble to remake from scratch all these shapes

Answer (score 3):

### Try this:

Select the object. Right-click to open the *Object Context Menu*.

Choose *Convert To* > Curve.